# Make changes to default msedge profile for new projects

Tags: visual-studio-code, microsoft-edge

In vscode I use the same `launch.json` for each project where I only change `url`:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Edge",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "pwa-msedge",
      "url": "http://localhost/test/${workspaceFolderBasename}/",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/",
      "outputCapture": "console",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "runtimeArgs": [
          "--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs"
      ],
      "env": {
        "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
        "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=9000"
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

This works great, since each project gets its own independent profile in MS Edge. However, this also means, for each new project I have to *manually* tweak settings of devtools, install required extensions, etc.

Is there a way to modify "default" profile, so when vscoded creates new profile it would already contain all the tweaks, extensions, etc?

I'm using portable vcode on Windows, so all the profiles saved in `.\data\user-data\User\workspaceStorage\**********\ms-vscode.js-debug\.profile`

vcode creates that folder, but I'm not sure if it actually copies anything into there, or MS Edge itself creates fresh profile in there,

Answer (score 0):

with [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates) you can create a `launch.json` and `settings.json` that will be placed in the workspace `.vscode` folder and they can contain snippets and variables.

```
##@@## ~w/.vscode/launch.json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    // add your launch configs
  ]
}
```

I will add the possibility to have variables in the final file like `${workspaceFolder}` and not be replaced by the extension when instantiating a template.

Comment: It's not settings for vscode I'm referring to, it's the profile of edge that vscode launches. It would be the same for chrome I assume.

Comment: @vanowm Then why tag the question with VSC, it is an Edge question you have, I have never used profiles in Chrome, all debugging works for me

Comment: because vcode launches the browser, it adds necessary flags, params, etc

Comment: It seems VSCode creates new profile in `.\data\user-data\User\workspaceStorage\*\ms-vscode.js-debug\.profile` (I'm using portable version on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you can try to create default profile for each project, just use the argument `--user-data-dir`. In your example, you just add this to `runtimeArgs`.

But when you do not configure this parameter and the corresponding group policy, it will default to this path: `C:\Users\<Current-user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default`.

For more details, please refer to this doc: [Create Microsoft Edge user data directory variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-create-user-directory-vars#path-variables).

Comment: vscode launches edge with that argument by default. I suspect vcode creates an empty folder and MS Edge fills it with fresh profile. That profile is not based on "default" profile from `C:\Users\<Current-user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default`

Comment: Whatever, you can use this argument to specify the path you need to create a new profile.